# JButton stays gray while yielding within actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

In my program, I have a button that when clicked will "generate a pattern" of clicks to be followed (Simon Says), within the generate pattern function it will set a button's color as 'brightened' and then default whilst yielding in between. The problem is that while yielding, the button stays "grayed" as if it has been clicked. Is there any way to prevent the graying without multithreading (I don't want it to get messy anymore than it is)? I can post the full source code if needed, but here are the parts that are doing it.
One last thing, I know the answer is probably very obvious but as you can probably tell by my code my brain works in an unorthodox manner.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ //button creation within init of applet
        JButton button = new JButton(); 
            button.setName("" + colorToChar[i]);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    if(simonDebounce == false && pattern[currentIndex] == (button.getName().charAt(0))) { //debounce is false and the current check is equal to the pattern
                        score ++;
                        currentIndex ++;
                        if(currentIndex > (pattern.length-1)){
                            sleep(100);
                            generatePattern(currentIndex);
                        }; //make it harder by increasing the pattern length by "1" will change later
                    }else if(simonDebounce == false && pattern[currentIndex] != (button.getName().charAt(0))){ //you can click and the you clicked a wrong button
                        score = 0;
                        sleep(100);
                        generatePattern(3);
                    };
                };
            });
            button.setBackground(defaultColors[i]);
        root.add(button); //root is a JComponent container
        button.setBounds( 100 + (i > 1 ? 150 : 0), 100 + ( i % 2 == 1 ? 150 : 0 ), 125, 125);
        buttons[i] = button;
    };
    sleep(3000);
    pattern = generatePattern(3); //start with three
```

Here is generatePattern

```
protected char[] generatePattern(int count){
    char[] newPattern = new char[count];
    currentIndex = 0;
    simonDebounce = true; //Dont count button clicks
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        int patternIndex = pseudoRandom(1, 4) - 1; //Random color
        newPattern[i] = colorToChar[patternIndex]; //'r', 'g', 'b', 'y' -> Don't mind this weird way of doing this, I'm much more used to more fluid languages
        buttons[patternIndex].setBackground(brightenedColors[patternIndex]);
        sleep(500);
        buttons[patternIndex].setBackground(defaultColors[patternIndex]);
        sleep(500);
    };
    pattern = newPattern; //a global 
    simonDebounce = false; //You can click a button
    return(newPattern); //returned, although not used anymore
};
```

Comment: You're blocking the event dispatching thread, which is bad

Comment: Without unblocking that thread (multithreading), it won't reset it's state by itself (until your processing is done)

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

Comment: Thanks, I would have rather not used multi-threading though, but if I have to then I will. Also is there anyway I can close this question?